# Firebase Messaging Error on MacOS and Web

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I’m using Firebase Messaging on iPhone and Android without any issues. However, when the following row of code is executed on MacOS and Web:

`String token = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();`

I’m receiving the following error:

> FLTFirebaseMessaging: An error occurred while calling method
> Messaging#getToken, errorOrNil => { NSLocalizedFailureReason =
> "Underlying error: The operation couldn\U2019t be completed.
> SecItemAdd (-34018)"; NSUnderlyingError = "Error
> Domain=com.gul.keychain.ErrorDomain Code=0 "SecItemAdd (-34018)"
> UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=SecItemAdd (-34018)}";

Does anyone know why I’m receiving this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For web, you must [pass the VAPID key](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/client#access_the_registration_token) to the getToken method so you can generate the token.